# Can't click the button - element not visible

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium and chrome drive and i can't click the button, 
I tried different approaches but nothing:

```
link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn buttonContainer arrow']"));

link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn buttonContainer arrow']"));

link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button']"));

link = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button'][value='btn buttonContainer arrow']"));
```

error massage:

```
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.96)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10240 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
```

code:

```
<a class="ng-scope" ng-if="!loginCtrl.pageObject.isDebugMode" ng-click="rootCtrl.redirectToRegistration()">
      <button class="btn buttonContainer arrow">
         <span>Enter</span>
      </button>
</a>
```

thanks Amir

Comment: paste url to this button so one can try it

Comment: Which button do you want to click?

Comment: the Enter Button

Comment: Check my Answer and update me. Thanks

Comment: nothing means what ? Getting any error ? or click is not working

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want to click on `Enter` button try: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn buttonContainer arrow']/span"));`

Comment: thanks but still i get an error "element not visible"

Comment: Ok :) atleast we are able to find the element now which is not visible. But that's a separate Question all together. Induce some `wait` before you try to find the element. Can you Accept this Answer ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didnt reproduce it but you should be able to get it to work like this:

```
firefoxDriver.findElement(By.className("buttonContainer")).click();
```

This approach is working for me using Selenium V2.52.0

Answer (score 0):

Use some `implicit wait` default in your script to locate the element by selenium before throwing the exception

Like

```
driver.get("your _site_url");               
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Use explicit wait until your element get visible and then perform click

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn buttonContainer arrow']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn buttonContainer arrow']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are automating a web-based application built using AngularJS.

In such a case, your `click()` events should be targeted to the web elements which have `ng-click` attribute.

Try clicking on the anchor link instead of the button.

```
link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn buttonContainer arrow']/.."));
link.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are multiple web elements in the DOM with same xpath and the first element is not visible although Firebug would highlight visible element (It typically happens with Responsive websites)

You can try following:

```
public WebElement getDisplayedElement( WebDriver driver ) {
                    try {   
                        WebElement visibleElement = null;
                        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(locator);
                        for (WebElement element : elements) {
                            boolean isDisplayed = false;
                            boolean isEnabled = false;
                            System.out.println("Count of element(s) from locator " +locator+ " is " +elements.size());
                            isDisplayed = element.isDisplayed();
                            isEnabled = element.isEnabled();
                            if(isDisplayed && isEnabled ) {
                                System.out.println("Found enabled and displayed web element");
                                visibleElement = element;
                                break;
                            }
                        }           
                        return visibleElement;    
                    }
```